# javascript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

Why does this not work?

```
var celsius = 12;
var fahrenheit = celsius x 1.8 + 32;

console.log(fahrenheit);
```

I am brand new to javascript. This comes up as a syntax error, could someone explain why this does not work?

Comment: Use `*` for multiplication not `x`.

Comment: Stop. Get a book on Javascript. Read it. If you use Stack Overflow for extremely simple problems like this you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: As @Will indicated, StackOverflow is not suited for extremely simplistic questions like these. You may want to have a look at [How do I ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to approach StackOverflow as a complete beginner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254572/what-is-the-proper-way-to-approach-stack-overflow-as-someone-totally-new-to-prog?rq=1)

Comment: It's ok man, don't freak out. It was just a simple question. I understand what you mean, but there's nothing wrong with me asking this question. I'm going through a uni course right now and just started the first lesson, reading material is later on in the course. So, yeah.

Comment: @Will thank you for those links

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong with asking extremely simplistic questions. It's considered an abuse by the system, and you can get your account locked for it. Even IP blocked. Just a heads up, you might want to use SO later when you *really* have hard problems...

Comment: 95% of programming languages use `*` for multiplication. Where did you ever get the idea that `x` was the multiplication operator?

Comment: @Will just wanted to say thanks for your advice this long ago, looking back on this question now, I realize how stupidly simple it is and I am now asking way more complicated questions than this now. I'm on track to be a data analyst and i'm loving it. Thanks again.

Comment: You'll find yourself repeating this many times in your career, as you encounter new technologies or different types of challenges. The first and best thing to do is find a good book on the subject. Within arms reach, I have five books on three different subjects, all purchased within the past two years, all of which helped me learn something new. I've been writing software for 12 years--it doesn't ever change.

Answer (score 0):

their is no x in javascript for multiplication use *

```js
var celsius = 12;
var fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32;

console.log(fahrenheit);
```